# API signature from the running process

Tags: windows, api, hook, process

I can read the DLLs involved in a running process through enumprocessmodules and I can reach the process IAT. Process IAT contains API adresses and not the name.

Is there any way to get the API  Name and signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the IAT must contain either the API name or function ordinal - otherwise the loader can't match up the imported function with an export from the DLL you've loaded. If you have the name it'll be an offset to a narrow string in your own process image; if it's the ordinal then you may be able to look up the function name from the ordinal in the imported DLL's export table, but it's not always supplied.

Unless your API name is a C++ mangled name you won't get the signature from here. You might be able to query the debug resource directory for a PDB and then use the PDB APIs to read the signature from that, if there's a PDB available.

Comment: Thanks Rup. There are cases for the non existence of PDB. Am I right?  On that situation, how do we acquire the signature?

Comment: Yes, depending on which DLLs we're talking about (Windows ones? third party ones?) you may not have one, or even one might not have been generated. In that case the signature probably won't have been saved anywhere and best you can do is use something like [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm) to analyse the code and hope it can pick out some of the signature. If you have stdcall function signatures _ABC@12 then you can use the number as the length of arguments etc. Or you can try and look it up in a .h file if you have one, but with macros etc. that might not be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of all the DLLs, you can walk the export address table of each to find the addresses of all the exported functions (and the ordinals and possibly the names, if the DLL had that information in it). From there, you can generate a mapping of function address back to the DLL and the exported function information. You will probably run into some difficulties dealing with forwarded exported functions, but it should be relatively straightforward.